# Why Datatable breaks the last bar using shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

We have an shiny app that encapsulate an DT that in turn contains a the green bar as shown at the picture bellow. Is there anyone that faced the same problem with the very last line? Other applications we have up and running works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: What is the code you used to generate this table ? Please edit your post and include the code.

Answer (score 3):

You probably used `styleColorBar`. With this function, the bar for the cell containing the minimum value has length 0, so the output you get is the expected one. To have a bar with a length proportional to the value, you can use my function `styleColorBar2` provided below. This function accepts two colors, one for the negative values and the other one for the positive values.

```
library(DT)

modelData <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B", "C"),
                        Current = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                        Modified = c(2500, 3500, 3000),
                        New_Membership = c(500, 500, -1000),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

styleColorBar2 <- function (data, color1, color2) 
{
  M <- max(abs(data), na.rm = TRUE)
  js <- c(
    "value <= 0 ? ",  
    sprintf("'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (1+value/%f) * 100 + '%%, %s ' + (1+value/%f) * 100 + '%%)'", 
            M, color1, M),
    " : ",
    sprintf("'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (1-value/%f) * 100 + '%%, %s ' + (1-value/%f) * 100 + '%%)'", 
            M, color2, M) 
  )
  JS(js)
}

datatable(
  modelData , selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
) %>% formatStyle(
  'New_Membership',
  background = styleColorBar2(modelData$New_Membership, "red", "lightblue"),
  backgroundSize = '100% 50%',
  backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
  backgroundPosition = 'center'
)
```